# Difference between if statement ways...?

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the shorthand notation for an if statement to shorten the following:

```
if (DCC.systemFlags[1]) { sf0CheckBox.Checked = true; } else { sf0CheckBox.Checked = false; }
```

And to use the following instead:

```
DCC.systemFlags[1] ? sf1CheckBox.Checked = true : sf1CheckBox.Checked = false;
```

However, I am not sure why I am getting the following error:

`Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

What is the correct way to write this?

`DCC.systemFlags[]` is an array of `bools`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you actually want is this:

```
sf0CheckBox.Checked = DCC.systemFlags[1]
```

Comment: Wow, talk about missing the obvious. It's Friday :P Thanks everyone for the quick responses.

Comment: I just refactored a bit of code today that had that "anti-pattern" on every single line. Luckily ReSharper sees it and rewrites it for you.

Answer (score 3):

What you really want in this case is:

```
sf1CheckBox.Checked = DCC.systemFlags[1];
```

But if you really wanted to use the ternary operator, this would be the way to do it:

```
sf1CheckBox.Checked = DCC.systemFlags[1] ? true : false;
```

The problem is that the ternary operator uses the following syntax:

```
[condition] ? [expression] : [expression]
```

`[expression]`s must evaluate to some value (e.g. `5 + 1`), and cannot be *statements* (e.g. `a = 5 + 1`).

Comment: Ow >.< \*washes eyes after seeing the second suggestion\*

Comment: Yeah, sorry @Mehrdad. I should've put a disclaimer or something on there. But the pattern can be useful if you're using it for something other than booleans, so I figured it had to be said.

Comment: That's not really correct. A statement like `sf1CheckBox.Checked = true` does actually have a value, the real problem is that the conditional expression can't be a statement. Also, the method call that you say that you can't make actually works just fine.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Save some soap for me. ;)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Nope. A statement like `a = 5 + 1` *does* evaluate to a value. That is not the problem with the code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no shorthand for a generic `if` statement.

One statement does *not* a ternary *operator* make, in C# syntax. :(

Edit: Take a look at others' answers for a shorthand for this *particular* `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to assign the value of one of the flags to the Checked property, all you need is this:

```
sf0CheckBox.Checked = DCC.systemFlags[1]
```

Further to your question, the ternary operator expects to return a value - it is not a replacement for an `if() {}` construct.

Answer (score 0):

A ternary operator statement

```
a = b ? foo : bar;
```

directly translates to

```
if (b) { a = foo; } else { b = bar; }
```

You're getting that error because all you have is the latter part of your expression (i.e. the `b ? foo : bar` part). You're not using that snippet of code anywhere. It's not assigning anything, calling anything, incrementing or decrementing something and definitely not creating a new object. Hence, it's not a valid statement, hence the error.

It's **bad** coding style, but something like this should work:

```
bool sink = DCC.systemFlags[1] ? sf1CheckBox.Checked = true : sf1CheckBox.Checked = false;
```

just because now you're actually doing something (assigning to `sink`).

Let me reiterate **bad coding style** again. You'll do so much better refactoring your code to what the others are saying in their answers.